# lxml separates elements while beautifulsoup does not

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

lxml returns two items, while beautifulsoup returns only one.  Is that because the `<br/>` shouldn't be there and beautifulsoup is more tolerant of bad html?

Is there a better way to extract the location using lxml? The `<br/>` isn't always there.

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = '''<td class="location">
    <p>
    TRACY,<br/>&nbsp;CA&nbsp;95304&nbsp;
    </p></td>
'''

tree = html.fromstring(s)
r = tree.xpath('//td[@class="location"]/p/text()')
print r

soup = bs(s, 'lxml')
r = soup.find_all('td', class_='location')[0].get_text()
print r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a better way to extract the location using lxml? The `<br/>` isn't always there.*

If, by *better* you mean returning a result that is closer to its BS counterpart, then XPath expression that better resemble your BS code would be :

```
>>> print tree.xpath('string(//td[@class="location"])')


    TRACY, CA 95304
```

Furthermore, if you like excess white spaces to be removed, use `normalize-space()` instead of `string()` :

```
>>> print tree.xpath('normalize-space(//td[@class="location"])')
TRACY, CA 95304
```

Answer (score 0):

`element.get_text()` joins separate string runs; from the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

> If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, **as a single Unicode string**

Emphasis mine.

Use the [`Tag.strings` generator](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) if you want the individual strings:

```
>>> list(soup.find_all('td', class_='location')[0].strings)
[u'\n', u'\n    TRACY,', u'\xa0CA\xa095304\xa0\n    ']
```

If you wanted lxml to join the text, then just join the text:

```
r = ''.join(tree.xpath('//td[@class="location"]/p/text()'))
```

The [`string()` XPath function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) can do the same for the `<td>` tag:

```
r = tree.xpath('string(//td[@class="location"])')
```

Demo:

```
>>> ''.join(tree.xpath('//td[@class="location"]/p/text()'))
u'\n    TRACY,\xa0CA\xa095304\xa0\n    '
>>> tree.xpath('string(//td[@class="location"])')
u'\n    \n    TRACY,\xa0CA\xa095304\xa0\n    '
```

I'd use `str.strip()` on either result:

```
>>> tree.xpath('string(//td[@class="location"])').strip()
u'TRACY,\xa0CA\xa095304'
>>> print tree.xpath('string(//td[@class="location"])').strip()
TRACY, CA 95304
```

or use the [`normalize-space()` XPath function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space):

```
>>> tree.xpath('normalize-space(string(//td[@class="location"]))')
u'TRACY,\xa0CA\xa095304\xa0'
```

Note that `str.strip()` removes the trailing non-breaking `\xa0` space, while `normalise-space()` leaves it.

Comment: I'm looking for a single string from lxml, not to further separate the bs result. "Is there a better way to extract the location using lxml?"